# What's a legit use case for a function call to be on left-hand side of assignment?

Tags: vba, compiler-errors

There's a compile error in VBA that reads as follows:

[image: Function call on left-hand side of assignment must return Variant or Object]

> **Compile error:**
>
> *Function call on left-hand side of assignment must return Variant or Object.*

To produce this compile error, you just need a function:

```
Public Function Foo(ByVal x As Integer) As Integer
    Foo = x
End Function
```

..And then a function call *on the left-hand side of an assignment* - for example:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Foo(42) = 12
End Sub
```

If I remove the `As Integer` return type from the function's signature, I get a function that returns an implicit `Variant`, and the compiler is satisfied - but now there's a run-time error 424 / "Object Required".

So I make the function return an actual object:

```
Public Function Foo(ByVal x As Integer) As Object
    Dim result As Collection
    Set result = New Collection
    result.Add x
    Set Foo = result
End Function

Public Sub Test()
    Foo(42) = 12
End Sub
```

Now at run-time the error is 438 / "Object doesn't support this property or method" - obviously, that `Test` method makes no sense whatsoever.

I cannot for the life of me think of anything that would be a valid, legitimate (and warranted?) use of a *function call on the LHS of an assignment*.

That compile error exists for a reason, so there *must* be a valid use case. What is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the function were to return a `Variant`, and that `Variant` contains an `Object` (i.e. the `Variant` type is VT_DISPATCH), **and** that object has a default "property put", then the assignment is valid, and the assignment is set to that default property.

In all other cases, it isn't.

Comment: Ok, so one could have a function that returns, say, a `Range` (e.g. in Excel VBA), and then one could do `MyFunction(foo) = "hi there"` and that would implicitly be the same as `MyFunction(foo).Value = "hi there"` - in other words any *legit* function call on the LHS of an assignment is assigning to the returned object's default property, and discards/leaves the object reference dangling. Correct?

Comment: @Mat'sMug: Yes, that would be one example. Did it work?

Answer (score 1):

VB variant is analogous to dynamic in C#, meaning that the type is dynamically resolved at run time. So it would make sense that you can assign a value to a variant type (i.e. the return value of a function that returns a variant type).

I imagine the use case is very narrow and 99.9% of the time, if you're trying to do this, you're doing something wrong.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/function-call-on-left-hand-side-of-assignment-must-return-variant-or-object

Comment: Plus one for the link. And I agree with the sentiment in your second paragraph.